# GoodData charts components throwing error of TypeError: item.predicate is not a function on setting color from configuration

Tags: gooddata

On setting colors from configuration and using Gooddata UI Charts component it is throwing following error
TypeError: item.predicate is not a function
[image: Error]

My config is as follows, On reseting default color it is working fine but as change color i get the colorMapping object in the api and after applying this config throwing the error.

How can i resolve it, Please help me out.

```
         config={{
            colorMapping: [{
              color: { type: "guid", value: "17" },
              id:"0d447449c2844b228923c37de7b6aaf9"  
            }]
          }}
```

Answer (score 4):

usage of ColorMapping is described in documentation
https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/chart_config.html#Color-mapping

You need to define predicate function which when returning true, will apply corresponding color (https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/ht_create_predicates.html).

In your case localId predicate seems to be right for you
https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-ui-sdk/blob/master/libs/sdk-ui/src/base/headerMatching/HeaderPredicateFactory.ts#L264

In case you are using older version of Gooddata UI.SDK than v8, you need to implement predicate by your own. Something like this (or equivalent for measures).

```
predicate: headerItem =>
        headerItem.attributeHeaderItem &&
        headerItem.attributeHeaderItem.localIdentifier === "0d447449c2844b228923c37de7b6aaf9", // find attribute item by localIdentifier
```

You can switch the official documentation to whathever version of Gooddata UI.SDK lib you are using and read the same article about ColorMapping
https://sdk.gooddata.com/gooddata-ui/docs/7.9.0/chart_config.html#color-mapping